# PHP Code Storing/Library Software

Tags: windows, php

Can anyone point me to any PHP code storing/library software. It is preferred to be free/open source though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating your own PHP Script connected to a database to store all your snippets, with search functionality as well, it'll be a fun project?

Or you can just use any PHP IDE, Dreamweaver CS4/CS5 or Eclipse etc. which normally come with ways of storing code.